# How can I convert this method from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++

Could someone explain how I'd write this to C#?

```
//byte[] buffer is priavte in the class
//it's for writing Packets (gameserver)
void writeString(int location, std::string value, int length) {
    if (value.length() < length) {
        memcpy(&buffer[location], value.c_str(), value.length());
        memset(&buffer[location+value.length()], 0, length-value.length());
    }
    else memcpy(&buffer[location], value.c_str(), length);
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of low-level byte manipulation that you almost never have to do in C#. Can you describe at a higher level what it is you are doing here? I can see that you are copying a string into a location inside a buffer, but why?  Is this to write to a file, or to maintain a list of strings, or what?  There is almost certainly an idiomatic, higher-level way to do what you want in C#.

Comment: @Eric Lippert am trying to write it inside a packet for gameserver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact answer to your question is this. This is a private method within a C# class (I also added the buffer byte array for clarity):

```
    byte[] buffer;
    private void writeString(int location, string value, int length)
    {
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        if (value.Length < length)
        {
            Array.Copy(encoding.GetBytes(value), 0, buffer, location, value.Length);
            Array.Clear(buffer, location, length - value.Length);
        }
        else Array.Copy(encoding.GetBytes(value), 0, buffer, location, length);
    }
```

C++ to C# migration pointers:

1. memset to zero is similar to Array.Clear
2. memcpy takes the destination first, whereas Array.Copy takes the source first
3. string.Length is a property, not a method as in std::string.length()

Answer (score 3):

Check out Buffer.BlockCopy

[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx)

Comment: I don't think `Buffer.BlockCopy` is an appropriate solution to this problem.  It's too low-level.

Answer (score 2):

[`ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) comes to mind. It takes your string as a parameter and returns a `byte[]` buffer containing your string.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to write binary data to a stream, file or similar? If so, you're probably better off using a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx), as it natively supports serializing strings (and other types, too, for  that matter).

Comment: Or [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)

Comment: am not it's for a game Packets

Comment: @MixedCoder, a BinaryWriter can do that too -- just point it to the right stream.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this to convert the string to a byte array, then use a for loop to put those bytes into the byte array that is your message buffer and to zero-fill if necessary

```
// C# to convert a string to a byte array.
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}
```